Okta OAuth2.0 with spring webflux issuer uri not working to display login page
Created account in okta to use oauth2.0, I am not able to get that login page detail after pasting issuer's uri in browser.
Code i integrated in my application

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeExchange(authorize -> authorize
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}


And here is application.yml file
server:
  port: 9098

spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
 
  application:
    name: API_GATEWAY

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            client-id: client-id
            client-secret: client-secret
        provider:
          okta:
           authorization-uri: https://dev-27305929.okta.com.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/authorize
            token-uri: https://dev-27305929.okta.com.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/token
            user-info-uri: https://dev-27305929.okta.com.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://dev-27305929.okta.com.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/keys



pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dummy.okta</groupId>
    <artifactId>OKTA-Dummy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OKTA-Dummy</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot okta reactive web</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

The project is reactive as i want to integrate this oauth in my microservice project that is why i am using @EnableWebFluxSecurity
enter image description here
check the image there is also redirect uri am i missing something like why am i not able to get any login page this below is the output i get after running my spring boot project
enter image description here
I want to get that login page of okta i am getting page not found after directly pasting issuer uri on browser directly

your Okta URLs looks malformed... it should be either ..okta.com or ...oktapreview.com. Can't be both. Please double check. Based on dev-xxx portion, my bet is - it should be https://dev-27305929.oktapreview.com
